# GPU's not detected in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow

On Jupyter VM when we execute nvidia-smi its detecting GPU in the backend, but its not showing up on the application when we try to run tensorflow by using commands. 
Commands :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Upon executing `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` we are getting false although GPU is getting detected on the backend.

Please provide some input if there is any idea to resolve this.

Comment: need more info. Which `tensorflow` version did you use?

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu? CUDA, cuDNN,....?

Comment: Version of tensorflow is 1.14.0